# In Django, how to pass selected dropdown value from template to view?

Tags: django

I searched for so long for a solution to this, but still can't find any. I have a big form in my template, which is actually composed of a bunch of model forms. One field in that big form is not part of a form, but is a single dynamic drop down menu populated from a table called "Institutions" in views.py as such:  Institutions.objects.all()

Here is the part from views.py:

```
def submission_form(request):

    institutions = Institution.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        abstractform = AbstractForm(request.POST)
        authorform = AuthorForm(request.POST)

        # Here I want code: if selected institution is this, then do that

        if abstractform.is_valid() and authorform.is_valid()
            new_abstract = abstractform.save()
            new_author = authorform.save()


     else:  
         return render(request, 'records/submission_form.html', {'abstractform': abstractform, 'authorform': authorform, 'institutions':institutions })
```

This is the drop down in my template:

```
 <select id="ddlInstititions">
    <option value="%">---------</option>
    {% for entry in institutions %} 
     <option value="{{ entry.id }}">{{ entry.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

My question is: Is it possible to pass that selected entry.name to the view so I can use it there? If not, what do you recommend doing instead?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order for any form element to be sent in the POST, you need to have a `name` attribute. So it should be `<select id="ddlInstititions" name="institutions">`.

What's passed to the view in the POST is the `value` attribute of each `option` element. Currently, you've set that to `entry.id`, so it's the ID that will be in the POST. You can either use that to look up the Institution object and get the name, or you can change the form so you put `entry.name` directly in the value attribute.

Comment: I believe he would need to add a 'name' attribute to the select list as well so it gets passed into the POST data.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery's $.ajax() for this.

In your Javascript, you can bind an event handler to `#ddlInstititions` via

```
$("#ddlInstitions").on("change", function(){
  var selectedValue = $(this).text();

  $.ajax({
    url : "insititionsSelectHandler/",
    type : "GET",
    data : {"name" : selectedValue},
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(){

    }
  });
});
```

What this will do is when you make a select event on the dropdown, it will fire this event handler.  You will have to define this URL in your `urls.py' like

```
(r'^/institionsSelectHandler/$', views.insititionsSelectHandler),
```

and you can get the value inside the view method like

```
def insititionsSelectHandler(request):
   key = request.GET["name"]
   ...
   ...
   ...
   #and return your results as a HttpResponse object that contains a dict
   return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"success" : "true", "message" : ... }, mimetype = "application/json")
```

Comment: Wow, it seems very tricky but not clear to others who will maintain the project.

Comment: @flyer, how so?  Seems pretty straightforward to me, and is one of the foundations of Ajax based web applications.  If you have several dozen of these in an unstructured js file, then yes it is a maintenance nightmare.  However, if you use design patterns like singletons and modules, maintenance and structuring becomes much easier.

Comment: Hi , I tried your helping code, but at the time of response it is not returning any return value to html page "department = request.GET["name"]
    print 'department----',department
    designations = []
    designations_params = Designations.objects.filter(department=department)
    for param in designations_params:
        designations.append(str(param.designation))
    print designations
    
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success" : "true", "message" :'got it'}, mimetype = "application/json"))" here return not working.. why?